# Javascript and jQuery: iterate through an array but wait for animations to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, loops

I have a simple example with several boxes to move across the screen. Each box shouldn't move until the previous one completes. I have a working solution using `.shift()` but I should be able to iterate through this using a for-loop and `$.each`. Anyone know how to get the for and `$.each` to work?

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/twinturbotom/j8XCw/) the shift button works the way I would like it to.

Thanks.

JS:

```
boxes = [
  ['.box0', 'animate', [ {left: '200px' }, 1000 ] ],
  ['.box1', 'animate', [ {left: '200px' }, 1000 ] ],
  ['.box2', 'animate', [ {left: '200px' }, 1000 ] ],
  ['.box3', 'animate', [ {left: '200px' }, 1000 ] ],
  ['.box4', 'animate', [ {left: '200px' }, 1000 ] ],
  ['div', 'animate', [ {left: '0px' }, 1000 ] ]
];
$('.eachMethod').click(animEach);
$('.ifMethod').click(animFor);
$('.shiftMethod').click(animShift);
function animEach(){
  $.each(boxes, function(){
    $.fn[this[1]].apply($(this[0]), this[2]).promise().done();
  });
};
function animFor(){
  for (i=0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    b=boxes[i];
    $.fn[b[1]].apply($(b[0]), b[2]).promise().done();
  }
};
function animShift(){
  b = boxes.shift();
  if (b) {
    $.fn[b[1]].apply($(b[0]), b[2]).promise().done(animShift);
  }
};​
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><button class='eachMethod'>$.each</button></li>
  <li><button class='ifMethod'>if</button></li>
  <li><button class='shiftMethod'>shift</button></li>
</ul>
<div class='box0'></div>
<div class='box1'></div>
<div class='box2'></div>
<div class='box3'></div>
<div class='box4'></div>​
```

CSS:

```
div{
 clear: both;   
 background-color: green;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 Position: relative;    
}
ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animate()` is asynchronous, so the loops will complete in a few milliseconds invoking the animation on each element virtually simultaneously. Your `.promise().done()` is not doing anything when you use the loops.

The version using `animShift()` is only applying the animation to one element at a time, and since the next call is within `done()` it won't fire until the first animation is complete

Comment: Thanks for the help; without the .promise() the next animation doesn't seem to fire.